# SetTextCursor in PyQt4

Tags: python, cursor, pyqt4

Every time textChanged() is emitted, the text of QTextBrowser is processed and then re-inserted in that QTextBrowser.
That causes trouble with the current Cursor.

How do I do that after typing something at | and re-inserting the text, the cursor is behind the newly inserted character (here: X) ?

```
Hello| World
```

Where it should be:

```
HelloX| World
```

Where it is:

```
|HelloX World
```

I need some help because I don't understand the according part of the QT documentation.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you're inserting text after the cursor, as yor example suggests, you, you should use the text cursor's [`insertText`](http://pyqt.sourceforge.net/Docs/PyQt4/qtextcursor.html#insertText) method instead of replacing the whole content of the editor - should save you some trouble:

```
editor.textCursor().insertText('X')
```

Otherwise you should be able to restore the previous position like this:

```
old_position = editor.textCursor().position()
# ...
new_cursor = editor.textCursor()
new_cursor.setPosition(old_position)
editor.setTextCursor(cursor)
```

Comment: No I have to use QTextBrowser to make hyperlinks to websites, haven't I?

Ok I already did what you said but it's not working... gets complicated because the text is edited by a thread

Comment: changed my example - keeping an old cursor sould be avoided, better to get a fresh one after changing the text.

Comment: Ok thanks... Now it works as intended, some different code screwed it up for me.